# Automating Javascript form creation from user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, user-input

I am trying to create a form which will generate different levels of forms based on the user input.

An example of this is 
"How many levels are there?" -User input 3-
Three separate levels will be generated each with the same questions. In this there will be a question asking "How many objects are there?" the same will happen here in that multiple options will be generated.

[Rough sketch of how the form would be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biuFS.png)

The problem I've been having with this is allocating ids and then being able to fetch them after so that they can be referenced for use and MySQL later down the line.

```
function generateForm(){
var number = document.getElementById('number_of_levels').value;
var div = document.getElementById('levels');
//  div.innerHTML += " " +number;

var heading = document.createElement("P");
heading.innerHTML = "Level " + number;    
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(heading);

var objects = document.createElement("P");

objects.innerHTML = "How many objects is the badge comprised of?";        
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(objects);

var num_objects_input = document.createElement("input");
num_objects_input.type = "number";
num_objects_input.id = "number_objects" +number;
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(num_objects_input);



//num_objects.onchange = function(){addObject(num_objects.id)};  

//div for the following levels
var ind_levels_div = document.createElement("div");
ind_levels_div.id = "level_" +number;
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(ind_levels_div);
num_objects_input.onchange = function(){additionalObject()};

}


function additionalObject(){
var number = document.getElementById("number_objects" +number).value;

var objects_number = document.createElement("P");
    objects_number.innerHTML = "Object " + number;    
    document.getElementById("level_" +number).appendChild(objects_number);
}
```

The result I'm getting is the form won't generate any Object form elements but will make the Levels.

Comment: Don't use I ids for but rather, store references to the elements as you create them:
 `var indLevelsDivs = []; indLevelsDivs.push(document.createElement("div"));` also, this shouldn't have anything to do with your database system.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Would I not need to know the ids to fetch values and pass into an MySQL statement?

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing with the forms?. Are you saving the form structure for reuse?

Comment: The end goal is to have the data collected and exported to an MySQL database but without limiting the amount of data the user can enter. The saved data should reflect the form structure since each "Object" is specific to each level.

Answer (score 0):

Store all of the form objects in an array then convert the array to a more readable format..

```
var objectArray = [];

function createObject() {
    var obj = document.createElement('div');
     objectArray.push(obj);
     obj.id = objectArray.length;
     number = objectArray.length;
     /* put your code here  to append obj to the proper level etc*/
}
```

Now you can just convert the array when you want to send it to mysql

```
 var sqlArray = JSON.Stringify(objectArray);
```